# How do i solve "'return' is not allowed here" in Firebaseauth method?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication

```
fun login(username: String, password: String,auth:FirebaseAuth): Result<LoggedInUser> {

            lateinit var Result_: Result<LoggedInUser>

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) run {
                        val fakeUser = LoggedInUser(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane")
                        Result_ = Result.Success(fakeUser)
                        return Result_//'return' is not allowed here
                    }
                }.addOnCompleteListener { exception ->
                    Result_ = Result.Error(IOException("Error logging in", exception.cause!!))
                    return Result_//'return' is not allowed here
                }

           return Result_ //its works but Result_ is not initialized

    }
```

there is a problem in login function, I wanna create user by FirebaseAuth but I can't write return in addOnCompleteListener and addOnCompleteListener also these methods is async if I could write return it couldn't work true. Because login function is working earlier than these methods . How can I solve this ?

Also I tried use other thread GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {} but it didn't work because

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

 //...

 return@launch Result_ //Type mismatch.Required Unit
}
```

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Comment: Since you're using Lotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will also help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can add 4th parameter as function which we can use as callback

```
fun login(username: String, password: String,auth:FirebaseAuth,callBack:(Result)->Unit): Result<LoggedInUser> {

            lateinit var Result_: Result<LoggedInUser>

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) run {
                        val fakeUser = LoggedInUser(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane")
                        Result_ = Result.Success(fakeUser)
                        callBack(Result_)
                    }
                }.addOnCompleteListener { exception ->
                    Result_ = Result.Error(IOException("Error logging in", exception.cause!!))
                    callBack(Result_)
                }

    }
```

Now just call function like this

```
login(userNameVariable,passwordVariable,authVariable){result->
   // do your operation with result
}
```

Comment: Thanks but login fun is running later than the codes written after it , like async function .
So I cant use result